# Tense choice problem

Tags: grammaticality, tense

> I have to go to sleep because I have a class [-----] at 7:30 A.M.

In the above sentence, which of the following fits correctly in the blank, and why?

- begin
- begins
- is beginning
- began

Comment: You should a choice for present participle 'beginning'. So the sentence could be: I have to go to sleep because I have a class beginning at 7:30 a.m.

Comment: The sentence works quite well without adding anything in the blank.

Comment: How do I ask a mod to edit my comment? I missed out 'have' in my first comment (above).

Comment: @EnglishLearner: In general, if you didn't notice a mistake in your comment within the first 5 minutes (during which time you can just edit it yourself), I think the easiest solution is to just copy the text, delete the comment, and paste the copy into a new comment which you can then edit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

None of the above are strictly correct.  A proper construction would be the following:

> I have to go to sleep because I have a class **that begins** at 7:30 A.M.

(Note you could also say "which begins" instead of "that begins"; either is fine.)

To explain why, let's deconstruct the sentence.  We begin with the simplest part:

> I have to go to sleep.

That's fine as a sentence on its own, but raises the question of *why* you have to go to sleep.  The answer is "because you have a class." So we build on the construction:

> I have to go to sleep **because I have a class**.

Now the author of the sentence wants to add more to the sentence; they want to describe that class.  You must sleep because you have a class; what *kind* of class do you have?  A class that begins at 7:30 am.  And now we've arrived at the complete construction:

> I have to go to sleep because I have a class **that begins at 7:30 A.M**.

Comment: Thank you but I still need to know why I should add "that "?

Comment: @user1218 Because you're adding a clause that describes the class you have.  "I have an apple *that is* red." "I have a dog *that likes* bacon." When you're describing an object, you use *that* (or *which*) to add the description. I have a dog. What kind of dog? A dog that likes bacon.  "A dog likes bacon" without the *that* means that any dog in general (and therefore *every* dog) likes bacon.  If you have "a dog *that* likes bacon", you have one dog that specifically likes bacon (you're not saying every dog likes bacon, only this one).

Comment: @user1218 [This EL&U answer](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/35588/22119) might help. As the poster mentions, here 'class' is the subject of the clause, so you must use 'that'.

Comment: Ok if i have this example : The plane ........ at ten tomorrow .
 Should i say (leave ,will leave ,leaves ,is going to leave )?

Comment: @user1218 "Leaves" (note the plural), "will leave" and "is going to leave" are all perfectly fine :)

Comment: Why not "Leaves" ? and if you have this question in multiple choice which choice is better ?

Comment: "Leaves" is fine to say! I'd have to see the question to answer that; all are perfectly valid, but the multiple-choice question might add extra information to help me understand which answer they're looking for.

Comment: Ok the last question because I do not want to open a new question for small things : "After she ....... her homework, she slept" (had finished ,has finished ,was finishing ,could finish) and why ?

Comment: @user1218 "Had finished" because 'slept' is past tense.  'Had' is also past tense; none of your other choices are.

Answer (score -1):

> I have to go to sleep because I have a class *that* begins at 7:30 A.M

You will need to add *that* in order to make the sentence correct.

Since class is singular, **begin** is incorrect. **begins** can be swapped with **is beginning**, but that is less common for this purpose. <strike>You hear **is beginning** with events like a music concert, where the beginning of the event may take some time to complete (at which point in time, you can say "the event began" or "the event has already begun")</strike>. **began** is the past tense, so it would not work here either. If you were talking about yesterday's 7:30 AM class, you could say that it began at that time.

In conversation, it is usually shortened to this:

> I have to go to sleep because I have a class at 7:30 A.M

Comment: *is beginning* is present tense. You can't say "I have a class that is beginning at 7:30 am" when 7:30 am is in the future.  You can say "I have a class that is beginning now", but not at 7:30; no more than you could say "I have a class that is beginning last night."

Comment: @WendiKidd , is this sentence correct:  I have a class beginning at 7:30 a.m.

Comment: @WendiKidd I was referring to slang usage. I should have mentioned that. Edited

Comment: @EnglishLearner I've been bouncing that one around in my head since I read this question. I don't *think* it's correct, though I won't say so 100%. What I know *is* correct would be "I have classes beginning at 7:30 a.m.", meaning you have more than one class and the first of those classes begins at 7:30.  I'm fairly sure that "a class beginning at" is not correct. I know it sounds wrong. I'd stick with "that begins at" or "which begins at" because even if it's right, it isn't common. (Sorry I couldn't be more decisive!)

Comment: @WendiKidd, See, your sentence 'I have classes beginning at 7:30 a.m' seems a bit odd because most people would not have multiple classes starting at the same time. At least I think people wouldn't be signing for classes that didn't fit in their schedule.

Comment: @EnglishLearner It's a different type of sentence that I don't have the technical know-how to explain. It doesn't mean that multiple classes start at the same time, it means that you're in classes that day and the first one starts at 7:30. Sort of like "Ugh, I'm in meetings all day; starting at 9 a.m. I'm booked solid!" Shorter (and definitely more formal/less common) version: "I have meetings beginning at 9 a.m."  I have meetings today. When do I have those meetings? Beginning at 9am. Sorry I don't know how to be clearer than that. Need StoneyB or the like to come explain with proper terms!

Comment: @WendiKidd I tried to look-up in the dictionary. It doesn’t say that ‘beginning’ is present participle of begin. Can an expert clarify if beginning is present participle? I was trying to use beginning as an adverb in this sentence: I have a class beginning at 7:30 a.m.

Comment: @WendiKidd: It's perfectly okay to use present tense when referring to something that will happen in the future. For example, I can introduce you to *Mr Smith, [who is retiring tomorrow](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22who+is+retiring+tomorrow%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1)*

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Idiomatic English isn't as logical/constrained as you might like. It's perfectly normal to say *"I have classes beginning at 9am tomorrow"*. The plural doesn't imply multiple classes all starting at 9am - it just means you do actually have more than one class scheduled for the future (probably, more than one class *tomorrow*, but even that isn't certain). And that the *first* such class starts at 9am.

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Also, in your *I have a class beginning at 7:30 a.m.* the word beginning couldn't possibly be an *adverb*, because the only other verb in the sentence is *have*, and there's no way it modifies that. It's a present participle, forming part of the "adjectival" phrase *beginning at 7:30 a.m.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers thanks. Dont you mean adverbial phrase? It answer the question 'when'.

Comment: @EnglishLearner: Depends how you want to look at it, I guess. I put the word "adjectival" in quotes because I know it's a loose usage. But a more typical [adverb phrase](http://grammar.about.com/od/ab/g/adverbphraseterm.htm) such as *"I'm revising for tomorrow's class **more thoroughly than usual**"* clearly "adverbially" modifies the verb *(revising)*. Me, I'd say your example "adjectivally" modifies the noun *(a class)*.