# "Neither of the twin brothers paid attention to their (his?) studies"

Tags: pronouns

1. Neither of the twin brothers paid attention to **their** studies.
2. Neither of the twin brothers paid attention to **his** studies.
   I'm confused with the use of **their** or **his** in the above sentences. Are both correct? Please explain it to me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: I would use *his* since both twins are male. This is similar to *Each of the twin brothers paid attention to his (not their) studies.* If the twins are mixed (a male and a female), then  using '[singular they](http://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/usage-of-they-them-their-in-place-of-he-him-his-or-she)' (as in your sentence 1) is a good option.

Comment: Neither of the twins paid attention to their studies. You mean it is a good option. Thanks again, GoDucks.

Comment: Related: http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4682/9346

Comment: @GoDucks- You should post your excellent comment as an answer, so this will no longer show up as "unanswered." Good job, as always.

Answer (score 1):

> Are both [sentences] correct?

Yes, both sentences are correct.

> Please explain it to me.

As [GoDucks](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/27803/goducks) was kind to reference, the [singular they](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/62371/usage-of-they-them-their-in-place-of-he-him-his-or-she) is an excellent way to sidestep the need to dive into gender politics to write a sentence. It even accomplishes this without excluding those of non-binary gender (such as intersex individuals) or dehumanizing the subject with words like ***it***.

Comment: http://www.isna.org/faq/hermaphrodite

Comment: Thanks for bringing that up, Snailboat. I've updated the wording to what I now understand is the correct clinical term (which was what I thought, in my ignorance, the word hermaphrodite ***was***).

Answer (score 0):

I'd say only this sentence is correct:

> Neither of the twin **brothers** paid attention to **his** studies.

The singular `their` is used when (a) gender is unknown, (b) gender is possibly fluid (e.g. a group that might have intersex individuals), or (c) more than one gender is represented (e.g. a co-ed class). This is a convenient replacement for the clumsy `his and her` and respectfully recognises more than the binary male and female.

Since the sentence refers to twin *boys*, none of the above conditions apply, and there is really no reason to avoid the conventional `his`.