# Be verb after "nor"

Tags: word-choice

Given only the below 2 sentences, should the verb following "nor" be am or are?

> Neither you nor I am happy
>
> Neither you nor I are happy

My bet goes to "am".

Well, thank you for kind support.

Comment: Related/duplicate: [Using plural or singular verb after “neither” and “none”](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/using-plural-or-singular-verb-after-neither-and-none).

Comment: @Em. Thank you for the link.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using plural or singular verb after "neither" and "none"](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/4682/using-plural-or-singular-verb-after-neither-and-none)