Neither of the girls brought "her" homework or neither of the girls brought "their" homework?
I am struggling with this one. Should the pronoun match 'neither' (singular) or 'girls' (plural)?

See also answers at https://ell.stackexchange.com/q/4682/138287

People increasingly use their as a gender-neutral pronoun in such contexts, so it's a really bad example. What you should be asking is what form of verb should be used in Neither of the girls like / likes doing homework. As that linked chart shows, both pluralities are in common use - anyone who claims one version is "wrong" is just a pedant.

The girsl are plural

@FumbleFingers If it's perfectly acceptable to write "neither of the girls are", does it follow that it's equally correct to write "either of the girls are"? Or is it just that usage has admitted the first but not the second.

@RonaldSole - It is also never clear whether either of them are supposed to be particularly good at their chosen vocations. 2024 'Guardian' review of 'The Palace' (German TV series). But... Gordon Brown and George Osborne have much more in common than either of them is happy to admit. (same paper, 2014)

@RonaldSole: I'd say "correct" isn't a useful term here. But maybe that's because I'm a Brit, and we've never been so fixated of identifying and enforcing syntactic conformity (witness company is / company are in BrE and AmE). I doubt if either of us are interested in learning rules as such, but if you follow that link and switch corpus from BrE to AmE you'll see Brits are more accepting of that plurality.

Some sources are strict that in formal spoken or written English, the correct sentence would be Neither of the girls brought her homework..

In formal styles, we use neither of with a singular verb when it is
the subject. However, in informal speaking, people often use plural
verbs:
Formal: Neither of my best friends was around.
Informal: Neither of them were interested in going to university.

Neither as a determiner (Cambridge Dictionary)
Merriam-Webster says: 'Some commentators insist that neither must be used with a singular verb.', but adds:

It generally is, but especially when a prepositional phrase
intervenes between it and the verb, a plural verb is quite common.

M-W quotes CP Snow:  neither of those ideal solutions are in sight.

I think especially when a prepositional phrase intervenes is just part and parcel of the idea that the more text there is between the actual "subject" neither and the associated verb, the more likely we are to choose the plurality that suits what we want to convey, rather than slavishly following the rule "either/neither are always singular". So after A couple of solutions were proposed..., you'll rarely find ...but neither are ideal. And obviously ...but neither solution are ideal is impossible because of singular "solution". But the Snow example is perfectly idiomatic to me.

@FumbleFingers - When I see the 'plural' variant, it doesn't set off any alarm bells, but if I think about it, I'll say to myself that 'neither' means not either one of two things or people and that is very much a singular-leaning notion.

Well, we've only got to consider "a norange" and "a whole nother ball game" to realize that language doesn't have to be burdened by what has been. Basically, it's whatever floats your boat (as long as it's a reasonably well-recognized tide! :)

From a leading UK educationalist, I heard: "One in every eight students at British universities are now Chinese." Floated her boat but mine went aground.
